# Cannot connect to FTP on Ubuntu 16.04 from FTP client

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-16.04, proftpd, vsftpd, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have an Alibaba ECS Ubuntu setup and everything works fine except that I cannot access my FTP from any other FTP client. I get the timeout error
I have setup the ufw rules to allow incoming as well as tried disabling the firewall still the same error.

I can however login to FTP using localhost or private IP when am logged into the management terminal.

I have tried both vsftpd and proftpd.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: People actually can get help from this question. Upvote from me. Thanks for the answer too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the firewalls settings done using `sudo ufw` through the terminal does not reflect at all. I had to use the ECS instance manage->security groups->add security rules (or use qucikly create rules to add multiple rules) to add desired ports and allow ips (0.0.0.0/0 ) to allow from any.
Conclusion: Use the ECS manage console to set firewall rules